# Espresso RecyclerView Error - No view holder at position

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I'm running an Espresso test to click on an element of the RecyclerView.

```
   onView(withId(R.id.recyclerList)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(2, click()));
```

However, I'm getting the following error: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: No view holder at position**

I've checked the view id is pointing to my RecyclerView and my dependencies are as follows:

- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2

Comment: did you manage to solve it? I'm having the exact same problem and no one is answering my question either

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to solve :-(

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which reproduces the error.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I think I had the same problem and I managed to solve it.

The problem was that *unless you are using an AsyncTask* to populate the RecyclerView, Espresso **doesn't** wait for the background thread to complete before performing the next operation.

So, it would search for the item at *position 2,* and since your background thread is still running and the recycler view hasn't loaded yet, it would return the IllegalStateException.

Even though I **wouldn't** suggest using this, you can check if the test works very quickly, by adding a Thread.sleep() (with a reasonable time), like this:

```
    @Test
    public void myTest() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        onView(withId(R.id.recyclerList))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(2, click()));

        //assert something
}
```

The ***better (and correct) solution*** to this problem, is using [Idling Resources](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource.html).

This [short and concise video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCtzH0Rz5XU) really helped me understand how to use IdlingResources (CountingIdlingResources in particular).

Your ui test should now look something like:

```
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        registerIdlingResources(/*put your IdlingResource here*/);

        onView(withId(R.id.recyclerList))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(2, click()));

        //assert something
}
```

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the possible issue is that your item actually not visible when you are trying to perform your action. If so, you can try `onView(withId(R.id.recyclerList)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(2))`
and then perform your action

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CountingIdlingResource` class that will make sure that your data is loaded in your recycler view before running the test by calling `increment()` on your **counting idle object** before fetching the data, then calling `decrement()` on your **counting idle object** after the data has been loaded.

The first thing to do is to add the dependency to use the `CountingIdlingResource`

```
implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.3.0'
```

In your Activity define a global **public** variable of type `CountingIdlingResource`

```
public CountingIdlingResource idlingResource = new CountingIdlingResource("Loader");
```

"Loader" is just a unique id for your Idling Resource (From docs: the resource name this resource should report to Espresso.)

Then before fetching your data from the data source just call `idlingResource.increment()` and after the data is fetched just call `idlingResource.decrement()`

The final Step inside your **RecyclerViewTest** class is to add your **activity rule**

```
@Rule
public ActivityScenarioRule<YourActivity> rule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(YourActivity.class);
```

then inside your **test** method

```
@Test
public void recyclerViewItemClick() {

    rule.getScenario().onActivity(new ActivityScenario.ActivityAction<YourActivity>() {
        @Override
        public void perform(YourActivity activity) {
            IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(activity.idlingResource);
        }
    });

    onView(withId(R.id.rv)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(2, click()));
}
```